# wcf common interface with Task based async client

Tags: .net, wcf

How to declare common interface for client and server in case of using Task based asynchronous operations on client ?

```
// Server side interface
public interface IService
{
    string GetString()
}

// Client side interface
public interface IClient
{
    Task<string> GetStringAsync()
}
```

But in this case dublication of operation declaration needed and client side must declare attribute parameters  ReplyAction, ResponseAction to understand server GetString operation as GetStringAsync.

How to declare common interface for client and server to minimize errors ?